# Java - array is being changed for no reason

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this program which takes a 2D array of letters, and scrambles them. However, one line of my code changes a separate array for literally no apparent reason whatsoever?!

Here's the code:

```
private String[][] words = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}};


public Scramble()
{
    String[] a = words[2];
    // At this point, a = {"g", "h", "i"}
    words[2][0] = words[0][2];
    // After this line, a changes to {"c", "h", "i"}
    words[1][2] = words[2][1];
    words[2] = words[1];
    words[1] = a;
}
```

Why is it doing this?!

Comment: Reference `a` and `words[2]` are both pointing for same array object.. I guess you can make out the reason from this.

Comment: But after the line `words[2] = words[1]`, `words[2]` now equals `{"d", "e", "h"}`, but `a` still equals `{"c", "h", "i"}`???

Comment: Because then, you changed the reference `words[2]` to point to a completely different array.. Whereas, changing `words[2][0]`, you are just changing the 1st index of the array.

Comment: Everything you should know to understand this is: `String[][] = (String[])[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like all Java objects (as opposed to Java primitives), arrays are reference objects. When you do this

```
String[] a = words[2];
```

`a` becomes an alias to `words[2]`'s content array. Whatever changes you may make to `a` are happening to `words[2]` simultaneously and vice versa, because there is only one array object referenced from two places.

When you make this assignment

```
words[2][0] = words[0][2];
```

you take a word from `[0][2]` (i.e. `"c"`) and copy it in place of `"g"` into the array `words[2]`, which is also the array `a`. Hence the change of `a`'s content that you observe.

If you do not want `a` to change when you make changes to `words[2]`, make a copy instead of simply assigning the array:

```
String[] a = Arrays.copyOf(words[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are confused by how java's assign by value assignment of arrays works similar to assign by reference in other languages. They way it works is in the process of assigning

```
String[] a = words[2];
```

You are indeed initializing a new string array *a* and setting it equal to the value stored by variable *words[2]*. But **array variables store addresses**, therefore `String[] a` is ready to take an address (reference) from the address stored in `words[2]`. In this manner they point to the same space in memory, that one dimensional array `[g, h, i]`

When you go to change `words[2]` and see the same change in `a` this is because writes to the array alter only the memory spaces being pointed to, not the pointers. `a` and `words[2]` will always have the same values.

Comment: About your `pass by reference`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.